# I think a better knowledge of javascript array methods will help me?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update an array of products in a custom mutation in keystone-next. I have got as far as the below, which works for the first product in my array. Obviously this only works if there is only 1 item in the array.

I know I need to map through the array in some way but I can't get my head round it.

```
const productIds = user.cart.map((cartItem) => cartItem.product.id);
console.log(productIds)
await context.lists.Product.updateMany({
  // this is the bit that's wrong
  data: [
    {
      id: productIds[0],
      data: {
        status: 'PENDING',
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: it's because you have only passed the first element of the array. You can iterate over the array items to pass it one by one

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to map through your array of `productIds`

```js
const productIds = user.cart.map((cartItem) => cartItem.product.id);

productIds.map(async (id) => {
  await context.lists.Product.updateMany({
    data: [
      {
        id,
        data: {
          status: 'PENDING',
        },
      },
    ],
  });
})
```

But most efficiently you should handle the `update` in the first `map` without getting the array of `productIds` first. Like this

```js
user.cart.map(async(cartItem) => {
  await context.lists.Product.updateMany({
    data: [
      {
        id: cartItem.product.id,
        data: {
          status: 'PENDING',
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this u mean?

```
const productIds = user.cart.map((cartItem) => cartItem.product.id);
console.log(productIds)
await context.lists.Product.updateMany({

  data: productIds.map(productId => ({
      id: productId,
      data: {
        status: 'PENDING',
      },
  }))

});
```